# Calculate shortest cycle that contains node $s$

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Let $ G(V, E, w)$ be a graph with no negative weights.

Describe an algorithm that returns the shortest cycle containing a node $ v $.

I came across this algorithm https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs374/sp2017/labs/solutions/lab10-sol.pdf

I can't convince myself it is true, because $ d(s,v)+w(s,v)$ might not be independent.

By that I mean that perhaps $w(s,v)$ is contained in $d(s,v)$.

An algorithm I came up with is as follows:

```
Result arr=[]
For x in N(v):  // N is neighbours of v
    remove(v,x) // remove the edge (v,x)
    T=Dijkstra_tree(x,G)
    if(v is in T):
        Add d(v,x)+w(v,x) to Result Arr// add the weight of the tree+ the removed edge to arr
return Min(Result arr)
```

This algorithm has a running time of $O(|V|)(|E|+|V|\log(|V|)$.

Because $v $ might have $|V|-1$ neighbours, and then we run Dijkstra every time on them.

The algorithm they presented has a much better complexity but I just can't convince myself it indeed works.  My algorithm fixed that issue, but costs a lot of runtime.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why does the algorithm presented in the link work?
And if it doesn't, does the fix I provided make it work?

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected? The algorithm in the link works for directed graphs (and is correct)

Comment: I assumed the solution to both would be the same, but in this instance I was working on an undirected graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question "why is the linked algorithm correct?", first of all notice that it works for *directed* graphs.

We want to show that the shortest cycle containing $s$ consists of a shortest path from $s$ to some vertex $v$ plus the edge $(v,s)$ such that $d(s,v) + w(v,s)$ is minimized.

Let $C = \langle s=v_0, v_1, \dots, v_\ell, s\rangle$ be a cycle.
Clearly, the length of $C$ is at least $d(s, v_\ell) + w(v_\ell, s)$.
On the other hand, all shortest paths $\pi$ from $s$ to a vertex $v$ such that $(v,s)$ exist imply the existence of a cycle of length $d(s,v) + w(v,s)$ (notice, in particular, that any simple path from $s$ contains no edges entering $s$, hence $\pi$ does not already contain $(v,s)$).

Answer (score 0):

In an undirected graph $G$, remove vertex $v$ and find the shortest path between all pairs of vertices in $N(v)$; i.e. Find $d(a,b):=$shortest path between $a,b\in N(v)$ in graph $G'=G-\{v\}$.

Result is $min\{d(a,b)+w(a,v)+w(b,v)|a,b\in N(v)\}$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if $G$ itself is a cycle of length $> 3$.

Comment: If $G$ is a cycle $v,a,v_1,...,v_n,b,v$ then by removing  the vertex $v$ we find the shortest  path $a,v_1,...,v_n,b$ between vertices of $N(v)$ and addition of $w(a,v)$ and $w(b,v)$ produces the cycle.

Comment: Oh, you meant $N(v)$ as the neighborhood of $v$! I think you should add that to your answer.